# Python reading pdf files

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

How can i use jupyter lab to read and extract tables from pdf files

A typical pdf file with text tilles subtitles and tables in between. I need the coding to extract the table under a specific title, and cleaning some unwanted text like page numbers

What are some of the coding to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabula-py: you can parse a PDF and convert it into a CSV, TSV, JSON, or a pandas DataFrame.